# Chat Server: chat history error java

Tags: java, network-programming, serversocket

The problem is that I need to show chat history on the client side without transferring the chat file. The server and the client are on the same machine ie my pc. The server reads char by char from file and writes it on the socket. The client needs to read it as string to get exact chat history as saved in file. But by my method it is printing single char in single line.

```
    import java.io.*;

    class Server
    {
        public static void main(String dt[])
        {
            ServerSocket sskt=null;Socket skt=null;
            InputStreamReader isrin=null,isrout=null;
            BufferedReader brin=null,brout=null;PrintWriter pw=null;
            FileWriter fw=null;FileReader fr=null;
            DataInputStream dis=null;DataOutputStream dos=null;
            try
            {
                sskt=new ServerSocket(1234);
                System.out.println("Waiting for Client");
                skt=sskt.accept();
                System.out.println("Connected to client");

                isrin=new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream());
                brin=new BufferedReader(isrin);

                isrout=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
                brout=new BufferedReader(isrout);
                pw=new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(),true);
                dis=new DataInputStream(skt.getInputStream());
                dos=new DataOutputStream(skt.getOutputStream());

                SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yy");
                Date date=new Date();
                String ing=sdf.format(date);
                fw=new FileWriter(ing+".txt",true);

                //do{
                String str;
                str=brin.readLine();
                int c=Integer.parseInt(str);
                switch(c)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        System.out.println("New Chat Stared");
                        String msg="";
                        do
                        {
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf1=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
                        Date d=new Date();
                        String in=sdf1.format(d);

                        msg=brin.readLine();
                        System.out.println("Client says " + msg);
                        fw.write("Client "+in+" "+msg);

                        msg=brout.readLine();
                        pw.println(msg);
                        fw.write("Server "+in+" "+msg);
                        }
                        while(!msg.equals("bye"));
                        fw.close();
                    break;
                    }
                    case 2:
                    {
                        String d=brin.readLine();
                        File file=new File(d+".txt");
                        if(file.exists())
                        {
                            dos.writeBoolean(true);
                            System.out.println("Displaying Contents of File");
                            fr=new FileReader(d+".txt");
                            int z;
                            while((z=fr.read())!=-1)
                            {
                                pw.println((char)z);
                            }
                            fr.close();
                            dos.writeBoolean(true);
//it writes the contents of the file on the socket one char by char
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dos.writeBoolean(false);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        case 3:
                        {
                            System.out.println("Client Exited");
                            System.exit(0);
                            break;
                        }
                        default:
                        {
                            System.out.println("Invalid choice");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                //}while(true);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    pw.close();
                    brin.close();
                    isrin.close();
                    skt.close();
                    sskt.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Client
    {
        public static void main(String dt[])
        {
            Socket skt=null;
            InputStreamReader isrout=null,isrin=null;
            BufferedReader brout=null,brin=null;
            PrintWriter pw=null;
            DataOutputStream dos=null;
            DataInputStream dis=null;
            FileReader fw=null;
        try
        {
                skt=new Socket("127.0.0.1",1234);
                System.out.println("Connected to Server");

                isrout=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
                brout=new BufferedReader(isrout);
                pw=new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(),true);
                isrin=new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream());
                brin=new BufferedReader(isrin);
                dos=new DataOutputStream(skt.getOutputStream());
                dis=new DataInputStream(skt.getInputStream());

            //do
            //{
                System.out.println("1. To start a chat");
                System.out.println("2. To view chat history");
                System.out.println("3. Exit");
                String str="";
                str=brout.readLine();
                pw.println(str);
                int a=Integer.parseInt(str);
                switch(a)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        String msg="";
                        do
                        {
                        msg=brout.readLine();
                        pw.println(msg);
                        msg=brin.readLine();
                        System.out.println("Server Says " + msg);
                        }
                        while(!msg.equals("bye"));
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2:
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter date of chat history");
                        String date=brout.readLine();
                        pw.println(date);
                        if(dis.readBoolean())
                        {
                            System.out.println("Chat Exists");
                            fw=new FileReader("H:\\Java Programs\\chatser\\chat\\client\\"+date+".txt");
                            int ab;
                            while((ab=fw.read())!=-1)
                            {
                                System.out.println(brin.readLine());
                            }
                            fw.close();
                        } //this syntax will read from the socket char by char and print one char after another in next line. i need to get chat history as string without copying the file at client side
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Incorrect Entity");
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3:
                    {
                        System.out.println("Thank you");
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        System.out.println("Incorrect Entity");
                    }
                }
            //}while(true); 

        }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    pw.close();
                    brout.close();
                    isrout.close();
                    skt.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And do you have a question?

Comment: the problem is that i need to show chat history on the client side without transferring the chat file. the server and the client are on the same machine ie my pc. the server reads char by char from file and writes it on the socket. the client needs to read it as string to get exact chat history as saved in file. but by my method it is printing single char in single line

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chat Server: Print chat history java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276435/chat-server-print-chat-history-java)